# How to relation some rows from one related table row?

Tags: sql, dql

How can I execute a query to select the rows where a related table (which has some related rows to each row of the first table) has its `foo1` values `any equal/all equal/any not equal/all not equal` to 'foo2'. E.g. if I have this query:

```
SELECT c FROM `table1` c 
INNER JOIN `table2` p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
WHERE p.foo1 = foo2
```

will select the rows in `table1` where ANY `foo1` value in `table2` rows is equal to `foo2`.

But what if I want to select only if NOT ALL `foo1` values are equal to `foo2`?

Comment: You need to look at `EXISTS`, something like `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t WHERE t.convocation_id = c.id AND t.foo1 <> foo2)`.

Comment: @user2989408 - Thank you. Forgive my ignorance, but what is `<>` operator? Also, I don't want to check if exists any value, but if NOT ALL are equal

Comment: '<>' is the `NOT EQUALS` operator in SQL. If you think about it, "NOT ALL rows have val = 1" would translate to "there EXISTS at least one row WHERE val <> 1", and that is a situation `EXISTS` is used for.

Comment: Also if you could post some sample data and expected output someone could help you with the exact query.

Comment: @user2989408 - I think I get it with your third option. Is this checking all `table2` related rows?

Comment: You can also restrict the rows in `table2` by a `WHERE` condition as shown in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

1->> any equal to foo2

SELECT top 1 * FROM `table1` c 
INNER JOIN `table2` p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
WHERE p.foo1 like 'foo2'

2->> all equal to foo2

SELECT * FROM `table1` c 
INNER JOIN `table2` p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
WHERE p.foo1 like 'foo2'

3->> any not equal to foo2

SELECT * FROM `table1` c 
INNER JOIN `table2` p ON p.convocation_id = c.id
WHERE p.foo1 <> 'foo2'

Comment: Your third option has worked. But I'm not sure about the second one. Won't it select if ANY `foo1` value is equal to `foo2`?

Comment: we can use equal to opertor('=' or 'like') for compare varchar column.

foo1 like 'foo2' ->> appox equal to foo2
foo1 like '%foo2' -->> starting with foo2
foo1 like 'foo2%' -->> ending with foo2
foo1 like '%foo2%' -->> any position with foo2

Comment: I know. But think that there are SOME columns in `table2` that match the `p.convocation_id = c.id` condition. So it will match if ANY column has the `foo1` value to `'foo2'`. I'm looking for the match when ALL are equal to `'foo2'`